# How do I fix this plus method

Tags: java, object, indexing, methods

I need to create a method plus that takes a name and price of an item and an index position. if the array of items already has an item object in the index position return false, if not add a new item with the name and price into the index position and return true.

I have tried to do something similar to an addtoCart method for a shopping cart, but I do not understand the index position part.

Item Class:

```
    public class Item{
private double price;
private static String name;
    private int rating;

public Item (String n, double p){
    name= n;
    price = p;
}

public double getPrice(){
    return price;
}
public boolean equals(Item item2)
{
    if (item2.title.equals(Item.title)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Item Available Class

```
     public class ItemAvailable{
 private Item [] itemList;

 public ItemAvailable(itemList.length){
    itemList = new Item[itemList.length];
 }


   public boolean plus(String name, double price, itemList[])
    Item n = new Item(title, price, bookList[]);
    for (int i = 0; i<itemList.length; i++){
       if(itemList[i].name.equals(name)){

           return true;

        }
       else if (itemList.length == INITIAL_CAP)
           return false;
```

I expect the output to be true if there is space to add a new item and false if there is already an item object in the index position.

Comment: this syntax is wrong `public boolean plus(String name, double price, itemList[]) ` can you please modify it

Comment: Also `Item` class doesn't have a constructor to fulfill `new Item(title, price, bookList[])`

Comment: Also `bookList[]` is not defined